How to prove this commutative algebra problem?
$R$ is a nonzero commutative ring with unit, the $R^m \cong R^n$ implies $m=n$.
I try to apply the universal property of tensor product to this problem:
$$R^m \cong R^m \otimes_R R, R^n \cong R^n \otimes_R R$$
but I don't know how to get a mapping to make it easier to show the necessity of $m=n$.
any hint?

tensor by R/m for a maximal ideal m. Here, we assume R is not the zero ring

Thanks! It's much more clearer now!
